# Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data error in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-address, savedata

When i select shipping options and click on next button.
It gives me error as Unable to save shipping information. Please check input data.
The error is coming at this url /checkout/#shipping
I have updated the magento version from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3. This issue is coming in 2.3.3
What is the solution for this?

Error in network tab

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Phrase or null, string given, called in /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php on line 121 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:56
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php(121): Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException->__construct('Validate class ...')

## 1 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingProcessor.php(66): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement->assign('3302', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))

## 2 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendo in **/var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php** on line **56**

{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Phrase or null, string given, called in /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php on line 121 and defined in /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:56\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php(121): Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException->__construct('Validate class ...')\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingProcessor.php(66): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement->assign('3302', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendo' in '/var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php' on line 56","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}

Comment: Please check the exception log for more information about this error

Comment: 0-04-06 06:36:36] main.CRITICAL: The address failed to save. Verify the address and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\InputException(code: 0): The address failed to save. Verify the address and try again. at /var/www/vhosts/mobilemarkantennas.com/dev.mobilemarkantennas.com/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php:120)"} []

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski This is the error which i am getting, Any idea about this?

Comment: Can anybody help me plz

Comment: In your exception log you should find more information about this error.. By the way, your exception is thrown in: **/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php:120**
Replace  **throw new InputException(__('The address failed to save. Verify the address and try again.'));** with **throw new InputException($e->getMessage());** and you will see the specific error

Comment: When i inspect. in the network tab it gives me this error i have posted in my question